# Configure the memory limit per javascript process in FireFox

Tags: firefox, memory

Is it possible (how?) to increase the amout of RAM a JavaScript process may use in Firefox?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Which is not what I asked for. Any modern OS including Windows 95 will over-allocate memory and start to swap pages to disk if they do not fit in RAM. To prevent a random crash a program may impose a limit below the amount of physical RAM on how much memory it may use. I am asking for an option to configure this threshold.